# Azure ML PipelineData with DataTransferStep results in 0 bytes file

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am building an Azure ML pipeline with the azureml Python SDK. The pipeline calls a PythonScriptStep which stores data on the workspaceblobstore of the AML workspace.

I would like to extend the pipeline to export the pipeline data to an Azure Data Lake (Gen 1). Connecting the output of the PythonScriptStep directly to Azure Data Lake (Gen 1) is not supported by Azure ML as far as I understand. Therefore, I added an extra DataTransferStep to the pipeline, which takes the output from the PythonScriptStep as input directly into the DataTransferStep. According to the Microsoft documentation this should be possible.

So far I have built this solution, only this results in a file of 0 bytes on the Gen 1 Data Lake. I think the output_export_blob PipelineData does not correctly references the test.csv, and therefore the DataTransferStep cannot find the input. How can I connect the DataTransferStep correctly with the PipelineData output from the PythonScriptStep?

Example I followed:
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-with-data-dependency-steps.ipynb

pipeline.py

```
input_dataset = delimited_dataset(
    datastore=prdadls_datastore,
    folderpath=FOLDER_PATH_INPUT,
    filepath=INPUT_PATH
)

output_export_blob = PipelineData(
    'export_blob',
    datastore=workspaceblobstore_datastore,
)

test_step = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="test_upload_stackoverflow.py",
    arguments=[
        "--output_extract", output_export_blob,
    ],
    inputs=[
        input_dataset.as_named_input('input'),
    ],
    outputs=[output_export_blob],
    compute_target=aml_compute,
    source_directory="."
)

output_export_adls = DataReference(
    datastore=prdadls_datastore, 
    path_on_datastore=os.path.join(FOLDER_PATH_OUTPUT, 'test.csv'),
    data_reference_name='export_adls'        
)

export_to_adls = DataTransferStep(
    name='export_output_to_adls',
    source_data_reference=output_export_blob,
    source_reference_type='file',
    destination_data_reference=output_export_adls,
    compute_target=adf_compute
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    workspace=aml_workspace, 
    steps=[
        test_step, 
        export_to_adls
    ]
)
```

test_upload_stackoverflow.py

```
import os
import pathlib
from azureml.core import Datastore, Run

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("train")
parser.add_argument("--output_extract", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args() 

run = Run.get_context()
df_data_all = (
    run
    .input_datasets["input"]
    .to_pandas_dataframe()
)

os.makedirs(args.output_extract, exist_ok=True)
df_data_all.to_csv(
    os.path.join(args.output_extract, "test.csv"), 
    index=False
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example is immensely helpful. Thanks for that. You're right that it can be confusing to get `PythonScriptStep -> PipelineData`. Working initially even without the `DataTransferStep`.

I don't know 100% what's going on, but I thought I'd spitball some ideas:

1. Does your `PipelineData`,  `export_blob`, contain the "test.csv" file? I would verify that before troubleshooting the `DataTransferStep`. You can verify this using the SDK, or more easily with the UI.

   1. Go to the PipelineRun page, click on the `PythonScriptStep` in question.
   2. On "Outputs + Logs" page, there's a "Data Outputs" Section (that is slow to load initially)
   3. Open it and you'll see the output PipelineDatas then click on "View Output"
   4. Navigate to given path either in the Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer.
      [image]
      [image]
2. In `test_upload_stackoverflow.py` you are treating the `PipelineData` as a directory when call `.to_csv()` as opposed to a file which would be you just calling `df_data_all.to_csv(args.output_extract, index=False)`. Perhaps try defining the `PipelineData` with `is_directory=True`. Not sure if this is required though.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. You guided me in the right direction. I found the data in the correct spot (1). Playing around with the settings of directories and files gave the solution. In the end the issue was that I referenced a directory (export_blob) as source_data_reference for the DatatransferStep, while the destination_data_reference is a file reference. Changing the output to only reference a directory and setting source_reference_type to directory outputted the correct dataset on the DataLake

Comment: I am still playing around how to transfer files instead of directories with the DataTransferStep, because I don't want to transfer directories each time. So I need to find a way that PipelineData references a file. Any ideas for this?

Comment: OK found a workaround. Just updating filenames and referencing the directories does the trick. I can now write new files to an already existing directory on the data lake

Comment: @PhilipvanKuiken Do you find the document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-move-data-in-out-of-pipelines helpful?

Comment: @PhilipvanKuiken also to answer your question about `PipelineData` as a single file. It is possible to do this, just in your script, you would exclude the `os.path.join()` and just save like this: `df_data_all.to_csv(args.output_extract)`. This makes the `PipelineData` a single file.

Comment: @AndersSwanson Do you have any idea on this specific error, which is being thrown while setting up DataTransferStep pipeline.
`Unexpected error: User ComputeName: cpu-cluster
User ComputeType: BatchAI
For DataTransferStep, compute_target needs to be of type `DataFactory' (Azure Data Factory)`

Comment: @nikn8 sounds like this should be a separate stack overflow question. but my first thought it that the error message seems to describe the solution: "`compute_target` needs to be of type `DataFactory`' (Azure Data Factory)" Read more on [azureml-sdk's DataFactoryCompute page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.compute.datafactorycompute?view=azure-ml-py)